# PHP - Greater than but less than function

Tags: php, formatting

I am trying to run a greater than/less than function in my code.  I was able to get it to work for just one value, but if I try to complicate it further it doesn't like it.

Right now it says if it's greater than 180 days make it yellow otherwise don't shade the cell.  I want it to do the following: 
- not do anything if less than 180
- make it yellow if it equals 180 or more, but less than 730
- make it red if greater than or equal to 730

Here is my code so far

```
$rdata['Password last set'] = explode(' ', trim($rdata['Password last set']));
$rdata['Password last set'] = $rdata['Password last set'][0];
$day = 24 * 60 * 60;
if (isset($rdata['Password last set']))
if ((time() - (strtotime($rdata['Password last set'])) >= (180 * $day)))
print ("<TD bgcolor=yellow>{$rdata['Password last set']}</td>");
else
print ("<TD>{$rdata['Password last set']}</td>");
else
print ("<TD></td>");
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `date_diff()` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: thank you for your response Kyle - I'm stumbling through this project and I somehow got the above to work.  I'll definitely look up that other function you mentioned.

Comment: And use curly braces, for goodness' sake!

Comment: I see you are new user: do you know that you should "accept" one of the answers if it correctly answers your question? For this you click on the bird icon to the left of the answer, below the digit between two triangles. You can also click the triangles if you like an answer (up triangle) or dislike (down triangle).

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderGelbukh - this was a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$set = isset($rdata['Password last set']);

$delta = (time() - (strtotime($rdata['Password last set'])) / $day;

if ($set)
  if ($delta >= 730)
    echo "red";
  elseif ($delta >= 180)
    echo "yellow";
  else
    ; // otherwise the next "else" will be for "if ($delta)" and not "if ($set)"
else
  echo "<td></td>";
```

or much better

```
if ($set)
{
  if ($delta >= 730)
    echo "red";
  elseif ($delta >= 180)
    echo "yellow";
}
else
{
  echo "<td></td>";
}
```

or

```
if ($set):
  if ($delta >= 730):
    echo "red";
  elseif ($delta >= 180):
    echo "yellow";
  endif;
else:
  echo "<td></td>";
endif;
```

I would recommend to use `{ }` or `:` always except *maybe* when the expression under `if` occupies one line.